# Can be load and update data in one page using struts 2?

Tags: struts2

I wonder whether i can use 1 action to load data and update it?

It mean i have a page call about.jsp, manager will click a link to access this page. after redirect into this page, this page load content of about and update content if user edited data but two tasks can be use 1 action.

my i dea is, user use a action call AboutAction to load data to about.jsp page, after end user edited data on about.jsp and click submit, it will send data to AboutAction and update it?

Can i do that? and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing What you asked is one of the beauty of Struts2

**xml :**

```
<action name="AboutAction" class="AboutAction" method="load">
  <result>showMe.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">about.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="AboutAction" class="AboutAction" method="update">
  <result>showMe.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">editsuccess.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Action :**

```
  public String load(){
     //logic to load
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String update(){
     //logic to update
    return SUCCESS;
  }
```

Comment: excellent , but i have a other question, in your code, when dont care about execute method? it mean execute return SUCCESS or not we dont care, we just care about our method?

Comment: What you show are still two actions. You can map multiple actions onto the same method if you want as well... they would still count as separate actions. So the answer is effectively no, a single action can not do both... unless you decide to do something really weird.

Comment: @Quaternion but according to his last two lines it fits "my idea is, user use a action call AboutAction to load data to about.jsp page, after end user edited data on about.jsp and click submit, it will send data to AboutAction and update it?" Please if I am wrong correct me.

Comment: Oh is this example using dynamic method invocation (there is a '!' in the url)?